# How to restrict a user to run a particular job only in certain times per week

Tags: jenkins, time, permissions, jobs

I am creating a Jenkins job which will be used by another team to run some queries and extract data from database servers.
but I want them to be allowed to run the job only on Tue, Thur, Sat nights between 10:00PM to 2:00Am ( companies maintenance window).

So far I haven't found any solution in Jenkins pipeline for this, there is possible to timeout after some hours/minutes.. but I haven't found a way to define certain times in week.
and I am not sure If there is an option to restrict users permissions in order to be able to run a job in certain times!

I will appreciate any ideas / suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. You can achieve it in two parts.

Create a node, make the node to only be available during certain times. Assign a label to the node, restrict to run only jobs matching label. Configure job to run with same label.

Then restrict user access to only run that job(s). That will vary depending on the secuity model you are using.

In general, Authorization is not constrained by time, only access to resources (ie: jobs and nodes) and what can be done (run, config, etc.). Certainly nothing that sophisticated I am aware of for Jenkins. Nonetheless, the combination should get you what you need.

You can run multiple nodes on the same physical server, so you can just copy an existing node, add the label and cut the # executors if needed. You probably need a separate account to run agent under.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it can be having 2 parameters of type Active Choice Reactive Parameters.

1 Active choice Reactive parameter contains current system date using Groovy and have type as hidden HTMl. as shown below:
[1st active choice reactive reference parameter with current date time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSNt0.png)

2nd Active Choice reactive reference contains Java script for either deleting Build button or Disabling build button based current date gate from previous field.

Tried below snippet but I am weak at javascript so may need some changes.

```
return '''
<script>var startDate = Date(document.getElementById('current_date').value);
days=startDate.getDay();
hours = startDate.getHours();

if ( day != 2 && day != 4 && day != 6 && hours <=22 && hours>=2 ){
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0].remove();},500)
}
</script>
'''
```